# How to force java xml dom to produce newline after <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>?

Tags: java, xml, dom, formatting

I use this code to enable newlines:

```
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

But I get following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <child>aaaa</child>
</root>
```

I'd like to have newline before root element. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}indent-amount","2");
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. After putting `doc.appendChild(doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"myStylesheet.xsl\""));` before root creation, there's no linebreak before `<root>` and this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is :
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC,"yes");
                    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "10");

Answer (score 1):

Other answers did not work for me, or would be unacceptable in my application. This worked for me:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add the newline yourself by wrapping a `Writer` in a `FilterWriter` (or `OutputStream` in a `FilterOutputStream`) coded to recognize the end of that tag and add a newline, on the way out.

But that's a bit silly.  As Stephen C notes in his comment, you really probably shouldn't care about this enough to bother.

Answer (score 0):

When there isn't a DOCTYPE after the declaration or if you didn't specify the standalone attribut, the resulted xml file tend to have this problem.
If you don't have a DOCTYPE related to your file, put the standalone attribut at "yes".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can insert the newline manually. Assign the string to a temporary variable (let say its String temp). Then do somehting like this

```
String filteredStr = new StringBuilder(temp).insert(temp.indexOf('>') + 1, "\n")
                    .toString();
```